# What is the reason behind overriding a method/methods of an interface in the sub interface?

Tags: java, ooad

What is the reason behind overriding a method/methods of an interface in the sub interface?

for example

```
interface I{ public void method();}
interface I2 extends I{@Override public void method();}
```

Comment: you don't have to do it, if that is your question?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author of I2. While you're at it, ask why it has such a horrible meaningless name, why it has 0 documentation, and why it's not even formatted/indented properly. If you find a **real** example where that is done, ask about it (but the javadoc should make you understand why, and most of the time, being able to add/refine documentation for the method is the reason, like in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: I found it inside Spring API implementation.

Comment: @subhashis If my post fulfill what you expected please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to change the return type of your method to a sub-type of the original return type. eg:

```
interface I {
    public Object method();
}

interface I2 extends I {
    @Override
    public Integer method();
}
```

Or you can add `default` implementation to the method which is introduced in Java 8. eg:

```
interface I {
    public void method();
}

interface I2 extends I {
    @Override
    default public void method() {
        System.out.println("do something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. btw the `public` keyword here is superfluous, except in Java 9 where you can have private methods in interfaces.